# Android Работа с превью изображения с камеры

Tags: android, android-camera

Есть приложение, которое в реальном времени должно распознавать текст с камеры. Подскажите как понять, что нужно отправлять изображение с камеры на обработку(распознование текста), то есть что камера не трясется(или не сильно трясется) и изображение смазано.

Думал о том чтобы в методе onFramePreview проверять изображение на не смазанность(опять же вопрос как это можно проверить?).

Либо периодически вызывать метод onAutoFocus, в нем проверять изображение на не смазанность и в случае успеха отправлять на обработку.

Либо тупо периодически с помощью метода onAutoFocus получать изображение и отправлять на ообработку до тех пор пока не получим приемлемы результат.

Заранее спасибо)